# Re-apply jQuery select box styling when new select box is added to page

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery select box styling works on the initial page load, but when content with a select box is dynamically loaded into the page, the styling isn't applied to it.

What's the best way to make sure the new select box will be styled as soon as it is loaded onto the page?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.jStyling.createSelect(jQuery('select'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue when dynamically making tables with alternating band colors, this is how I did it:

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5fTt/)

HTML:

```
<input id="add" type="button" value="Add Box"></input>
<div class="styled">BOX</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addStyle() {
    $(".styled").css({
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "background": "#ff0000"
    });
};

$(document).on("click", "#add", function () {
    var myBox = $("<div>");
    myBox.addClass("styled");
    myBox.text("BOX");
    myBox.appendTo($("body"));
    addStyle();
});

addStyle();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CSS instead of jQuery

```
select {
    //Styling
}
```

Or by class or id if needed.

```
.classOfSelect {
    //Styling
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, this isn't a cross-browser friendly solution.

Comment: Why? CSS is, in general, cross browser. IE has some issues, but generally you want to put most of your styling in CSS